# spike testing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm new to jmeter, and I'm currently performing soak test using jp@gc ultimate thread group.The scenario is I want to perform the spike test within this soak test.So how can I perform it?

[The img shows the scenario in jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcg6C.png)

The above image shows the scenario. I want to perform spike test only in the jp@gc ultimate thread group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread group details are not visible. Personally I would prefer [Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to produce spike load.

The timer pauses threads until specified amount is reached and releases them in the same moment of time.

Comment: The 1st thread group has :---- Number of users : 1; Ramp-up period : 1; Loop count : 1 . The jp@gc ultimate thread group has start thread count : 10 ; initial delay : 01 ; startup time : 00 ; Hold load for : 7200 ; shutdown time : 0

Comment: This is not spike testing, this is normal load testing with 10 virtual users for 2 hours. See [Spike Testing definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing)

Comment: Can we combine soak test + spike test at the same time. For eg : Consider the scenario I'm hitting 10 users for 2hrs but in between of this 2hrs I'm hitting 300 users for 15-30mins. Is it possible.Please give the solution